# Spring caching solution with time based data

Tags: spring, caching

I'm a 'caching beginner' and I was looking at Spring's alternatives to solve the following requirements:

I have some time based data that is inserted into the database every minute. Once the data is inserted it will never be modified or deleted. Also, data will never be inserted in any days prior to the current one (no insertions 'in the past').

Users frequently request past data between a starting date and the current one. I would like their requests to be fulfilled by a mixed cache/database solution.

E.G. If an user requests last week of data once a day every day, I would like to access the cache for the first 6 days and the database for the last one. The cache would then be updated and I would have the same behavior the day after.

Is there a way to configure/implement this in a clean way using any of Spring's caching alternatives?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EHCache](http://ehcache.org/) support all of this and more and it [integrates with Spring](http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/) nicely.

*[update] - If I am reading your question right, you need to configure timeToLive and timeToIdle on your cache. All of this is documented in the main [configuration page](http://ehcache.org/documentation/configuration.html).*

Comment: Could you point me exactly where to look at in the documentation to figure out how to configure EHCache to fulfill my specific needs? What should I search for? Also, do you think I should use the new EHCache Search feature or will I be able to find a transparent solution? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I guess that the new features in EHCache_v2 like write-through and read-through might help me out in what I need. Hopefully..